# Reroute Android phone emulator to localhost

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, android, emulator

I need to force the Android phone emulator mapping, the way I have it configured in my `/etc/hosts` on my laptop. So I would want a situation where every time it tries to go to `my.great-website.local`, it targets my local host machine instead of going to the Internet. I have a configuration on my laptop where if I write `https://my.great-website.local` I am being redirected to the `localhost` environment. I would want to have the same effect on the emulator, but I see that its quite not easy to do. Is there an accessible `/etc/hosts` file on the emulator where I can try to reroute the request to `10.0.2.2` IP (special alias to my host loopback interfacem 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)?

EDIT:
I have found [a great instruction](https://medium.com/code-procedure-and-rants/use-modified-hosts-file-on-android-emulator-4f29f5d12ac1) on how I can edit `/etc/hosts` in the emulator which goes like that (MacOS specific manual):

```
Start Emulator
While on${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:

./emulator -list-avds
./emulator -avd <emulator-name> -writable-system

Define Emulator hosts
While on${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:

adb root
adb remount
adb pull /system/etc/hosts Downloads/hosts
echo ‘10.0.0.1 pretty.url.of.yours\n’ >> Downloads/hosts
adb push Downloads/hosts /system/etc/hosts
adb reboot
```

Unfortunately just after `adb remount` I get an error `Device must be bootloader unlocked`.

EDIT 2: Second option would be to run the emulator with a DNS that has this mapping done:

```
emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -dns-server 192.0.2.0,
192.0.2.255
```

But unfortunately when I tried `dnsmasq` I constantly got some permission errors:

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.224.5: Permission denied
```

If anyone finds an easy way to achieve this, I'd be really grateful for some help.